# CMake include Boost Beast (header only)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I want to include [Boost Beast](https://github.com/boostorg/beast) into my project. It's a header-only library. I have cloned the Beast repository into the same directory as my project.

I am using the following in CMake to include the header:

```
set(BEAST_INCLUDE_DIR ../beast/include)

include_directories(${BEAST_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES ${BEAST_INCLUDE_DIR}/boost/beast.hpp ...)

add_library(my_lib ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I'm including using the following (alongside other Boost includes):

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
```

But I get the following error:

> fatal error: boost/beast.hpp: No such file or directory

Do I need to do something special to include another "boost" directory?
The path of the header is:

```
beast/include/boost/beast.hpp
```

Comment: Use **absolute path** to include directories: `set(BEAST_INCLUDE_DIR `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../beast/include)`.
`

Comment: Whats your Boost and your CMake version?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried absolute path. Same problem.

Comment: @usr1234567 Boost 1.63.0. CMake 3.8.2

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating [an interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries) for Beast which you can then add as a dependency to your library.

**Create interface library for Beast:**

```
add_library(boost_beast INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(boost_beast
                           SYSTEM
                           PUBLIC
                           "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../beast/include")
```

Note in the call to [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) I've specified:

- `SYSTEM`: tells the compiler the directories are meant as system include directories
- `PUBLIC`: tells the compiler the directories should be made visible to both the target itself (`boost_beast`) and the users of the target (your library)

**Add Beast as a dependency to your library:**

Then you can add `boost_beast` as a dependency to your library:

```
add_library(my_lib ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(my_lib boost_beast)
```

At this point, `my_lib` will transitively have the Boost Beast include directory available to it.